# How did Batman see The Flash stumble?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, justice-league

In an action sequence The Flash is running around an empty industrial chimney and sees Wonder Woman reaching out to grab her sword and gives it a little nudge to push it back to her.

However, further on he stumbles (which to remind all, is very, very fast, so much the Flash is effectively a *blur*) and Batman helps him out.

Is this a careless execution of a scene by the director to increase the amusement of the film or do comic fans really have fan-theories about this?

Comment: That scene is to show good team work

Comment: I'm unsure what you're looking for here.  fan-theories would basically be speculation and aren't cannon to the dceu.

Comment: My understanding suggests that no one can see the Flash while he is on the move with the true exception being Superman. I would like to know if this was an errorenous scene or is because when the Flash stumbles human eyes can see him as a person?

Comment: Are sure you're not talking about the last fight scene, the one in Russia, right before Superman shows up.

Answer (score 4):

No, Batman doesn't help him, at all. After giving Diana her sword, Barry falls twice, once after tripping on stairs and once on Diana, trying to escape the falling rubble. Both times, he picks himself up.

I implore you to watch the movie again.

He does help him after he got his leg hurt by the Parademon, but no, he never saw Barry while he was speeding around.

After suggestion, I think you are talking about the reactor scene in Russia.What I think happened was that Batman saw was a blur of lightning and saw a Parademon attack what he assumed was Barry.

And in movie, the Flash was stumbling when Batman caught him, so he was not using Speed Force, but was still going at an astonishing speed.

I think this scene was meant to show us how fast Batman's reaction time is (it borders superhuman ).

Comment: I think both you and OP are mistaken. You're right about the fact that OP is confusing scenes. But OP is probably talking about the last fight with Steppenwolf in Russia: When Barry gave Cyborg a lift, he told him he was on _"bug duty"_ and then he ran around that industrial chimney and stumbled and Batman caught him. We can still see the thunderbolts so he was speeding.